# Создание таблицы рекордов в mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Добрый день. Хочу узнать как будет лучше и быстрее сделать таблицу рекордов в игре. Есть таблица с пользователями у которых есть рейтинг. Нужно отображать всегда 25 лучших игроков из миллиона или больше.
У меня в голове возникают два варианта.

1. делать выборку из всего количества игроков каждый раз когда игрок захочет увидеть таблицу рекордов.
2. завести ещё одну таблицу и каждый раз как у какого-то пользователя изменится рейтинг, проверять попадает он в ту таблицу или нет.

Второй вариант мне кажется более щадящим, но мне кажется что можно сделать как то красивее, но не знаю как. Может в mysql есть какие то инструменты которые помогут мне добиться желаемого? В общем для меня будут полезны любые предложения как можно организовать подобный топ игроков советы

Comment: кто записывает в базу? куда должно выводиться? когда записывается в базу?

Comment: в базу пишет игровой сервер на java. Сервер должен при соответствующем запросе клиента, отослать ему данные по рейтингу. Значение рейтинга изменяется только в конце битвы, скажем в рамках одного игрока это происходит раз в 5 минут непосредственно в игровой сессии

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 3.

Сделать в памяти статический список (игрок, рейтинг). Настроить таймер для обновления этой структуры из таблички в базе с интервалом. Интервал зависит от вашей задачи. На мой взгляд 30 сек или 1 минута вполне себе хорошо.

Этот вариант оптимизирован к огромному числу чтений и существенно разгружает базу.

Comment: а данный список можно сделать табличкой в базе? или проще и будет его хранить в другом месте?

Comment: В моем решении мы снимаем нагрузку с базы. Это используется при большом количестве запросов.

Comment: А в чём смысл? если есть все необходимые индексы, то нагрузка на базу минимальна. Почему все стремятся не использовать СУБД правильно (а она заточена для работы с данными), а пытаются в сторонке сделать свою версию? :-)

Comment: @Чад потому что при высокой нагрузке субд не справляются

Comment: @pavelip, обычно не справляется не потому что не может, а потому что ей забивают шурупы, вместо того чтобы её использовать правильно

Comment: @Чад при высоких нагрузках правильно использовать субд не удается. кеш в памяти всегда будет быстрее.

Comment: @Чад и даже с несколькими миллионами записей всё будет шустро работать?

Comment: @borisenki, так в этом то и суть индекса. хоть сто миллионов. Вы ещё предложите для oracl'a делать отдельную таблицу для решения этой задачи :-)

Comment: @pavelip, ну либо тогда не та СУБД, либо неправильное использование. СУБД ничего не мешает самой использовать кеш в памяти, и это будет намного быстрее стороннего кеша

Comment: @Чад спасибо, так и сделаю, а там посмотрю.

Comment: @borisenki если тебя волнует быстродействие(что при твоей задаче волновать не должно) - можно воспользоваться твоим 2 вариантом, но логику сравнения и записи поместить в хранимую процедуру, и эту "ещё одну таблицу" поместить в памяти. но это будет стрельба из пушки по тараканам.  А так, правильные индексы решат многое.

Answer (score 0):

А выборка из таблицы первых 25 значений, отсортированной по рейтингу, с учётом того что по полю рейтингу есть индекс чем плохо?

Это означает что на поле рейтинг есть индекс, чтобы при запросе база не перебирала все записи, а по факту брала только 25

Comment: ничем, вот испрашиваю. предполагается что значение рейтинга будет индексом?